# Which constructors can be generated by compiler automatically

Tags: c++11, constructor

For C++11, which constructors will be generated by `compiler` automatically, default/copy/move/deconstructor, I'm always confused about the rules, is there any reference/docs explaining it clearly? Any resource or answer would be appreciated.

In addition, what code style will make it clear, such as =delete or =default?

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying things, all constructors may be generated. But you should take into account that they don't always do what you'd expected.

So, there are rules of [three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), to guide you what and in which case you should write.